# How do I cancel external print jobs from Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I have an Excel add-in that I made that reads file names from a column, searches for PDFs that match that name using the Dir() function, and utilizes ShellExecute to print them all (or a selected subset of them)

I want to know if there is a way to abort all active print jobs from Excel VBA.  For example, if I realize that I accidentally triggered printing for 100 incorrect documents, I would like to be able to hit some kind of hotkey to stop and clear the print queue.  Note that printing will be on an undetermined network printer (whatever the default is for the computer that is executing this add-in).

Any advice that could put me on the right track would be appreciated.  I suspect it might involve using some kind of Windows libraries, but I honestly have no idea as I am a complete newbie at this.

Comment: You can cancel your print job from the machine from which Excel triggered the print job.

Comment: Right, but I would like to code a hotkey into my add-in as kind of an "oh s#!%" button

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Public Sub OhSht()
    Dim o As Object
    For Each o In GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer")
        o.CancelAllJobs
    Next
End Sub
```

To help debug you can use this version:

```
Public Sub OhSht()
    Dim o As Object, ret
    For Each o In GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer")
        ret = o.CancelAllJobs
        Debug.Print o.Name, ret
    Next
End Sub
```

It will list each printer and the result of the CancelAllJobs method on that printer.

A return value of `0` indicates success in the cancellation of all jobs on that printer.

A return value of `5` indicates that access is denied to that particular printer.

As far as I know there is no other possible return value. Please see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384838(v=vs.85).aspx).

**UPDATE**

This may help increase your access; try this version:

```
Public Sub OhSht()
    Dim o As Object, ret
    For Each o In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//./root/cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer")
        ret = o.CancelAllJobs
        Debug.Print o.Name, ret
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you excel hero, this looks very straightforward.  For anyone interested, I was able to search up this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394598(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Follow up question to this:  Would this cancel all jobs on all printers?  I feel like this could cause some issues if I am stopping all network printers that the machine has access to.

Comment: I believe the *dot* in this `GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")` limits this to only the local printers. Replacing that dot with the name of a remote server could allow the routine to kill other server's print jobs, but in that case the user running the code would need permissions set by the network admin to access the remote machine. Note, I cannot test this though because I do not have a network here.

Comment: Try this... Replace the `o.CancelAllJobs` line with this: `Debug.Print o.Name`. This will list all of the printers defined on your machine. You could limit the cancel to a specific printer by name... but that then means you need to know which printer the user just printed to.

Comment: @SBarry Please let me know if this is not going to work for you.

Comment: So a little follow up;  I tried going with some more complex methods using windows spooler API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861(v=vs.85).aspx)
It took me forever to figure out what I was doing, and unfortunately it did not work (I think that I did not have adequate permissions to use the SetPrinter function).  
Anyways, I just tried the code you gave me.  I was able to debug.print all the printer names successfully, but the "cancelalljobs" method did not seem to clear the print queue.   Is there some kind of error code to check to see if it executed?

Comment: @SBarry I have updated my answer with some code that may help.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I just tried with this code, and it seems that all printers have a return value of 5.  My user account is not any kind of network administrator, so am I out of luck?  Is there a way to just cancel the jobs printed from the local machine?

Comment: @SBarry Please try my new update at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Replaced the line in question, but unfortunately this gives the same result:  Error 5 on all printers

Comment: That's all I know on this subject. It sounds like your net admin has things locked down. If you cannot get them to increase your access then you are in a tough place. But look at the [WinNT example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/04/28/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-purge-all-the-print-jobs-on-a-windows-2000-print-server.aspx) on this page. Long shot, but it might work for you.